# Angular Directives: I have to call $apply twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

Here's the deal. I have a page where you just edit a user. It has basic inputs and everything. I then created a directive to handle uploading of images through ajax:

```
angular.module('fileDirectives', [])
.directive('fileUpload', ($http, $parse)->
    scope:
        fileUpload: "="
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
        if attrs.postUrl
            element.bind 'change', ->
                if this.files.length > 0
                    form = new FormData()
                    form.append 'files[]', file for file in this.files
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    req.open 'POST', attrs.postUrl, true
                    req.onreadystatechange = =>
                      if req.readyState is 4
                        if req.status is 200
                            response = JSON.parse req.responseText
                            notarray = attrs.notArray is "true"
                            if notarray
                                response = response[0]
                            scope.fileUpload = response
                            scope.$apply()
                    req.send form
```

The directive is used like this:

```
<input type="file" file-upload="member.image" post-url='/members/images' not-array="true"/>
```

Everything was working fine, but I wanted the user's image to be in it's own component, so I created a directive like so:

```
<member-img member='member' ></member-img>
```

Which uses the member's name and image to display a figure. If it'll help, here's that directive:

```
    ).directive('memberImg', ()->
    scope:
        member: "="
    restrict: "E"
    templateUrl: 'partials/member-image.html'
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
        failed = false
        setImage = ->
            scope.image = if scope.member.image and scope.member.image isnt '' and not failed
                scope.member.image
            else
                "default.gif"
        setImage()
        scope.$watch 'member.image', ->
            failed = false
            setImage()
        element.find('img').bind 'error', ()->
            scope.$apply ->
                failed = true
                setImage()
)
```

Anyways, for some reason by putting this into it's own directory, the image only gets uploaded 50% of the time. What's weirder is that in my fileUpload directive, if I call $apply twice, it works everytime:

```
.directive('fileUpload', ($http, $parse)->
    scope:
        fileUpload: "="
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
        if attrs.postUrl
            element.bind 'change', ->
                if this.files.length > 0
                    form = new FormData()
                    form.append 'files[]', file for file in this.files
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    req.open 'POST', attrs.postUrl, true
                    req.onreadystatechange = =>
                      if req.readyState is 4
                        if req.status is 200
                            response = JSON.parse req.responseText
                            notarray = attrs.notArray is "true"
                            if notarray
                                response = response[0]
                            scope.fileUpload = response
                            scope.$apply()
                            scope.$apply() # For some reason I have to call this twice.
                    req.send form
        else
            throw "fileUpload requires post-url attribute!"
```

I think what may be happening is that on the first apply, it's notifying the parent scope that member.image should change, then on the second apply the parent scope's notifying the other child that member should change. However, I know this is not intended behavior. Any light you could shed on the subject would be appreciated.